# Connect to local apache server via site domain

Tags: apache, http, centos, host, portforwarding

I'm locally running an apache web server using Centos (CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009). I used to be able to connect to this local server using a subdomain of mine "demo.mywebsite.com" by adding an A record pointing to my main IP address and forwarding the 80 port on my router to my server local IP.

This morning my router updated and reset by itself, and surprisingly I found out that the port 80 is no longer available for port forwarding since "it is used by the router interface". So now I can't access my server website using demo.mywebsite.com/foldername

I'm wondering if there's a way to access my server even without the ability to forwarding the 80 port.

Comment: This question does not look programming related (see [help/on-topic])... On top, you're mentioning that you're mapping port 90, but port 80 is not available.

Comment: @OlafKock yes, I’m sorry, I’ve misspelled. The port, of course, is always the number 80.